# Notification receive unstable

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm facing a problem with the new firebase notification system.

Sometimes the service works pretty well and fast, but other times the notifications aren't received by any device I'm sending to or it takes a long time (10 minutes to several hours). It doesn't matter if I send the notification from the firebase console or a data message from my PHP script. Nothing works. I send this notifications to a topic, but also the direct sending to a token won't work.
The console shows "0 send".

If I force the app to stop and restart it sometimes it fixes the problem and NEW notifications are received well.

It isn't reproducable, it's pretty random.

Are there some problems like this already known or am I the only one who is affected by this issue?

Here's my receving code:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d("FCM", "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        new MyNotification(remoteMessage, this).send();

        Log.d("FCM", "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d("FCM", "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
}
```

Notification Builder (shortened):

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext())
                .setContentTitle("Test")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setGroup(GROUP)
                .build();

NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getContext());
notificationManagerCompat.notify(ID, notification );
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the payload `priority` to `high`?

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue as well unfortunately.  Did you happen to find a solution?

Comment: The same happens to me, sometimes it works but sometimes the messages never come or come like 10 mins later all at the same time.

Comment: I experience the same issue. FCM is unreliable. Sometimes message is not delivered at all to the phone.

Comment: FCM is indeed highly unreliable, due to the [unrealistic heartbeat intervals in GCM/FCM](https://eladnava.com/google-cloud-messaging-extremely-unreliable/). Consider using [Pushy](https://pushy.me/), a reliable push notification service that greatly improves notification reliability on Android. Full disclosure - I work at Pushy.